# MYSQL QUERY count , how to?

Tags: mysql, count

I have table which has "prize" column.
In this column I have id of prizes.

I want to create query, which I will get all variants of prizes and count of them.

For example:

```
Prize 1 = 26 records
Prize 2 = 14 records
Prize 3 = 100 records
```

I'm trying to do this with :

```
SELECT COUNT(prize) FROM konkurs GROUP by prize
```

But this is not what I'm looking for :)

Any help ?

Comment: Can you post some data as an example?

Comment: prize is :`prize` int(1) NOT NULL,

values in `prize` are 1,2,3,4,5 and more.

I want to get info like: how many records have prize with each value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should print the price and its count.

```
SELECT COUNT(prize) AS count, prize FROM konkurs GROUP by prize
```

Answer (score 0):

your query gives exactely what you want. what's the problem? you can just add another column in the select query to show the prize id. 
`select prize, count(prize) FROM konkurs GROUP by prize`

Comment: Oh my god :) you are absolutely right.
thanks for hint!

Answer (score 0):

Change that `COUNT(prize)` to something like below using `CASE` expression like

```
SUM(case when prize = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as `Prize 1`
```